# Dimension Linear Algebra and Cardinality of a Set

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to prove the following proposition and find myself stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated. If the $\operatorname{span} ( I_1\cup I_2)\subseteq \operatorname{span}(I_1)$, then $\dim(\operatorname{span}(I_1\cup I_2))\leq |I_1|$.

Comment: Do you know that if $V\subseteq W$ then $\dim V\leq \dim W$?

Comment: I did not know that. How does that relate to the cardinality? That makes sense though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $V\subset W$ , then $\dim(V)\leq \dim(W)$, so $\dim(\operatorname{span}(I_1\cup I_2)) \leq \dim(\operatorname{span}(I_1)) \leq |I_1|.$

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but how do you $dim(span(I_{1}))\leq |I_{1}|$?

Comment: I appreciate your help though. That helps!

Comment: See you are looking at $span(I_{1})$, so $I_{1}$ is basically a spanning set for the vector space $span(I_{1})$. right? But any spanning set contains a basis! and dimension is precisely the cardinality of a basis.

Comment: Thank you! I understand it now.